# Polymer iron-ajax POST method not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, iron-ajax

I'm learning Polymer. I'm unable to figure the code to "post" using `<iron-ajax>`. I'm using an online testing API (https://reqres.in/), and I should receive this response back with status code 200:

```
{"token": "QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X"}".
```

I couldn't find a tutorial to show a `POST` example. I have been searching online for the past 24 hours, but everything is about `GET` and not `POST`.

If anyone familiar with `<iron-ajax>` could review my code and help me get it to work or figure out how to write the correct code, it would be very helpful for a beginner like me.

1. Is my code correct with the `body` property?
2. Is the response the `200` status code or the token?

   ```
   <!--
   @license
   Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
   This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
   The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
   The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
   Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
   subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
   -->

   <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
   <link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
   <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
   <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

   <dom-module id="my-view2">
     <!--test using this data: {
         "email": "peter@klaven",
         "password": "cityslicka"
     }-->
     <template>
       <iron-ajax>
           auto 
           method="post"
           url="https://reqres.in/api/login"
           handle-as="json"
           content-type="application/json"
           body =[{"email": "peter@klaven", "password": "cityslicka"}]
           on-response={{handleResponse}}

       </iron-ajax>

       <!--Handle response-->
       <p> response handling code goes here, how to show the response from the server here?</p>
       <p> It should show: {"token": "QpwL5tke4Pnpja7X"} </p>
       <div>
       <p> {{handleResponse}} </p>
       </div>
     </template>

     <script>
       class MyView2 extends Polymer.Element {
         static get is() { return 'my-view2'}; 

         static get proporties() {
           return {
             handleResponse: {
               type: Object,
               notify: true,
               readOnly: true 
             }
           };
         }
       }

       window.customElements.define(MyView2.is, MyView2);
     </script>
   </dom-module>
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your HTML is malformed (perhaps a copy-paste typo?). The `iron-ajax`'s attributes should be inside the opening tag like this:

  ```
  <iron-ajax
    auto
    method="post"
    ...
  >
  </iron-ajax>
  ```
- You probably meant to bind the `handleResponse` property to [`<iron-ajax>.lastResponse`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/elements/iron-ajax#property-lastResponse), which contains the response to the AJAX request.

  ```
  <iron-ajax last-response={{handleResponse}} ...>
  ```

  Note that the binding of `<p>{{handleResponse}}</p>` would render the response object as `[object Object]`. If you want to see the response contents, you'll have to use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) that returns a string (e.g., with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)) like this:

  ```
  // <template>
  <p>json(handleResponse)</p>

  // <script>
  class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
    ...
    json(obj) {
      return JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
  }
  ```
- The attribute value of `<iron-ajax>.body` should be single-quoted like this:

  ```
  <iron-ajax body='[{"foo": "bar"}]'>
  ```

The full example should look something like this:

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax
              auto
              method="post"
              url="//httpbin.org/post"
              body='[{"foo": "{{foo}}"}]'
              handle-as="json"
              content-type="application/json"
              last-response="{{lastResponse}}"
              >
    </iron-ajax>
    <pre>[[json(lastResponse)]]</pre>
  </template>
  <script>
    class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          foo: {
            type: String,
            value: 'bar'
          }
        }
      }

      json(obj) {
        return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
      }
    }
    customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VWYqRN?editors=1010)

Comment: My goodness that was such a complete and excellent answer. Thank you so much. I couldn't ask for better detailed answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Marco no problem :)

Comment: Can you extend your generosity for one more question? Could you help me with this issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459901/polymer-iron-ajax-get-method-retrieving-result-from-an-expressjs-route-returning