# Polymer Iron-Ajax Get Method retrieving result from an expressJS route returning res.json

Tags: json, heroku, polymer, iron-ajax

My api end point which running on Heroku free account(expressJS) url [IS HERE](https://shielded-caverns-24265.herokuapp.com/)

It shows json response from an expressJS route. The data looks like this

```
[{"_id":"5938b81bd263a5144c9d7d17","title":"mlab first entry","__v":0},
 {"_id":"5939efc7fac2b71aac4add11","title":"Second Entry","__v":0},
 {"_id":"5939efd0fac2b71aac4add12","title":"Second Entry","__v":0}]
```

My polymer code which I run from localhost(http://127.0.0.1:8081/view1):`

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">


<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template>

   <iron-ajax
      auto 
      url="https://shielded-caverns-24265.herokuapp.com/"
      handle-as="json"
      last-response="{{response}}">
   </iron-ajax>
 <<!--tried items={{response}} -->
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[response.title]]">
<div>
  <a href="{{item.title}}">   &nbsp &nbsp {{ item.title}}</a>
</div>
</template>


 <!-- this code works and pull the data from https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[response.data]]">
<div>
  <a href="{{item.first_name}} {{item.last_name}}"> {{item.first_name}}  &nbsp &nbsp {{ item.last_name}}</a>
</div>
</template>
-->


  </template>


  <script>
    class MyView1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-view1'; }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyView1.is, MyView1);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

`

But when I visit my polymer page, it is not showing any data...What am I doing wrong?

Here is my route code:

```
     router.get('/', function(req, res){
     Comment.find(function(err, comments){
        res.json(comments);
});
});
```

Do I need to format the server res.json? Or use res.format(object)?
 I appreciate any help here.

Comment: I get a CORS error when I try to access that Heroku endpoint from Codepen. That could be the reason why your app isn't displaying any data. Can you check the Network panel in DevTools? (the console might even show it)

Comment: That makes sense. I have to figure out how to do that in ExpressJS route so it allows communication from all. I'm grateful and thankful. You're so kind for taking the time to look into it. Have a great weekend.